# Adding Scope to function calls

Tags: c++, c

How would I make a function that allows you to open up brackets after the calling of the function, and declare code inside of the brackets, similar to this:

```
openScopeBrackets();
{
//...code here
}
closeScopeBrackets();
```

I've seen this with OpenGL, too:

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
{
//...code here
}
glEnd()
```

Please help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difficult to say what you want to do, but a Local scope is created just by adding `{` `}` inside the function body. The variables declared within this scope will not be visible outside it.

```
void doSomething()
{
    int i;
    {

        //Local Scope


    }
}
```

Comment: @TehCodr you can put a pair of brackets almost _anywhere_ to create a new scope. And that's all it does: create a new scope, so that variables declared inside the brackets will disappear at the ending `}`.

Comment: @TehCodr: anywhere you put `{` & `}` creates a local scope.

Comment: @TehCodr: It's not clear what effect you think it should have "with function calls". Using `{}` to create a scope is independent of any function calls. So it "works" with function calls, but it just does the same thing it would do without a function call.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: `Variables declared inside the brackets will disappear at the ending` would depend on their storage type. A `static` variable wont really disappear.It stays alive.

Comment: @Als true true, forgot about `static`.

Comment: I want to release variables at the end of the scope, because I'm mainly going to put in functions that change global variables, but I want to use temporary variables, to test the success of said functions.

Comment: @TehCodr: Temporary/Local Variables will indeed be destroyed once the control reaches `}`.

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++, a function can be called from any other function only. But we can NOT define functions in other functions. So, it is NOT possible to first call the function and then write the code for the called function.

```
void fName(){
    otherFunction(){//NOT allowed
        ...definition for otherFunction
    }
}
```

Comment: GCC accepts that as a language extension called nested function http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Nested-Functions.html but it only works for C, not for C++

Comment: I don't want to try func-ception, I just want to call a function, and then put declarations that go after the function, specific to the function, in brackets. Refer to glBegin and glEnd...

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to happen at the beginning and at the end of a block, you might use constructor/destructor for that.

Look at [QMutexLocker](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qmutexlocker.html) as an inspirational example to see what I mean.